# Refreshing a Fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity

In My Project, I am deleting records in the `recyclerview` based upon the id. Delete is working fine but once data got deleted then fragment is not refreshing the layout. Any help is appreciated.

**Code**

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this@ViewHolder)
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    var mPosition:Int=adapterPosition
    var item:TestCart=mList[mPosition]

    when(v!!.id)
    {
        deleteButton.id ->
        {
            deleteItem(item.itemId!!)
            mList.removeAt(adapterPosition)
        }
    }

fun deleteItem(id: Int)
{

    var db: TestDatabaseHandler = TestDatabaseHandler(mContext)
    db.deleteItem(id)
}
```

Comment: For future travelers, it might be worth knowing that Room ORM provides support for `LiveData<List<T>>` which you can feed directly into a `ListAdapter` in which case the diff and notify is automatic

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition)` below `mList` and it should work.